# How do I create a web service with HTTPS endpoint in Apache CXF

Tags: apache, service, web, cxf

I have Apache as front-end to my Tomcat server where I have deployed a CXF web service. All access to my web service happens through SSL which is handled by Apache web server. This means that my Tomcat server is totally unaware of SSL. As a result my CXF generated web service has a **http** endpoint URL. How do I make it **HTTPS** while giving the opportunity of handling SSL to Apache web server. Any clue to override endpoint **URL scheme**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do that, you should also set proper address (that with HTTPS) in publishedEndpointURL.
Like here: [How to start cxf service on localhost but return external address in wsdl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750683/how-to-start-cxf-service-on-localhost-but-return-external-address-in-wsdl)

This will make imports in generated WSDL point to proper URLs.

Answer (score 0):

In you case you need to enable [SSL connector for Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File) (in case you use `mod_proxy` in Apache), or you need to to enable secured AJP connector (in case you use `mod_jk`):

`<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443" scheme="https" secure="true" address="127.0.0.1" port="8009" />`

CXF is out of game here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it by using a JNDI lookup for a base URL, then constructing a url for publishEndpointUrl.  In XML config, it looks something like this:

```
  <jee:jndi-lookup id="ProxyURL" jndi-name="myProxyURL" resource-ref="true" cache="true" />     
 <bean id="EndpointURL"  class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="#{ProxyURL+'/myServiceAddress'}"/>
     </bean>
 <jaxws:endpoint
    id="myServiceEndpoint"
    ...[other parameters]...
    publishedEndpointUrl="#EndpointURL">
```