# Is is possible to have https service using cxf with tomcat(without jetty)

Tags: tomcat, https, cxf, embedded-jetty

Is it possible to deploy apache cxf-rs on tomcat using https protocol?
i see many example using embedded-jetty but i do not want it.

I should add more details here, I don't know how to exactly do it.I have bellow configs: in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in cxf-config.xml :

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

<bean id="smsserviceclass" class="com.isc.sg.services.rest.SmsGatewayService"/>
<jaxrs:server id="smsservice" address="https://localhost:8443/sg/smsservice">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="smsserviceclass"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

and also in server.xml the SSL is enabled on port 8443, but i get this exception:
java.io.IOException: Protocol mismatch for port 8443: engine's protocol is http, the url protocol is https

Comment: What does CXF-RS have to do with whether or not you can use HTTPS? Just set up HTTPS on Tomcat and deploy CXF-RS onto it.

Comment: Thsnks  Christopher Schultz, i added more detail to my question, i tryed to do it, but i have got exception

Comment: Sorry... out of my league, here. "Engine" here refers to CXF's engine? This is a "problem" with CXF, not Tomcat. Perhaps you have to configure the "engine" specifically to use HTTPS?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I believe the "engine" _is_ referring to Tomcat.

Comment: Also I don't see where Jetty is in play here - I do exactly what OP has done frequently. @MahtaMoradzadeh - take a look at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html (or equivalent for the version of Tomcat you are using).

Comment: It seems this is a configuration problem. The client is producing the exception, so we have no idea what "engine" means. If it means Tomcat, then Tomcat has not been configured properly. Tomcat provides no means for making outgoing connections, so the only thing you can configure is the `<Connector>` in Tomcat. Read @unhillbilly's comment for a reference to the Tomcat SSL documentation and make sure that everything else is working. Use `curl` or `openssl s_client` or something similar to make sure that SSL has been configured properly, first. Then try to connect as above.

Comment: when my app only have cxf config for https on jetty, it works fine.I mean when i use  jetty as built in server without config on tomcat bye this snippet of code:
<httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf" id="port-8443-tls-config">
         <httpj:engine port="8443">
             <httpj:tlsServerParameters>  ....
    
but I want to deploy my service on tomcat because I want to cluster my tomcat.
when I config connector on tomcat and remove above engine, I've got the mismatch protocol when I add the <httpj:engine-factory with tomcat connector together,I have got  "Address already in use: bind" exception.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of set the https url in the address attribute, the **jaxrs:server** element contains an attribute called `publishedEndpointURL` in which you can configure the URL of your service. After specifying that you can configure Tomcat to use HTTPS or put your Tomcat behind an Apache Server.

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750683/how-to-start-cxf-service-on-localhost-but-return-external-address-in-wsdl) and [here](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/How-work-publishedEndpointUrl-td4624660.html), note that this links refer to WS technology, but CXF is used in the process and both **jaxrs:server** and **jaxws:endpoint** have almost the same attributes.